# CSS3 Animations being triggered on display change

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

I am trying to use CSS3 animations in order to fade elements in on page load. With this I need to set the element to `display: none;` and then back to `display: block;`.

I only want the CSS3 animation to be used on the initial load of the element and not via the display. Is this possible without tracking that the animation has finished with JavaScript? I have a JS Fiddle example here https://jsfiddle.net/L219ezkd/1/

Comment: ehhh... `animation-iteration-count: 1` ?

Comment: still fires when you change the display via js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep the markup as-is and use the `visibility` property instead. On the `.hover-hide` element, toggle between `hidden` and `visible`.

[Updated fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/L219ezkd/3/)

(This works because the elements are absolutely positioned. If they were not, `visibility: hidden;` would not yield the desired behavior because it maintains the space used by the element and simply hides it instead of removing it altogether like `display: none;`.)

Comment: Yeah I see I am actually in a scenario where this is ok, I was hoping for an answer where this wasn't necessary (visibility) but if only way it shall suffice thanks

Comment: No problem. Just out of curiosity, why were you trying to avoid `visibility` if possible? It does have some benefits over `display` other than the one outlined here.

Comment: Mainly just because of not needing to use things like position making it a bit more flexible for future

Answer (score 1):

Wrap everything in a container and fade that in with css then show and hide your elements like you are doing right now:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="hover-hide" class="fade fade-in" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background:blue; display:block; position: absolute; top:0; left:0">  </div>
  <div id="hover-show" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background:red; display:none; position: absolute; top:0; left:0"></div>
</div>
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L219ezkd/2/)